# Inf2Cat Error 22.9.12 - INF cannot be copied to %Windir%

Tags: windows, batch-file, driver, cat, inf

I am making a driver official for Windows 7 as it it unsigned and the process to disable things to make the unsigned driver work is much more hassle then to actually sign the driver.

Well, in order to sign the driver, first I need to make the catalog file for the driver using the latest Inf2Cat from the [Windows Driver Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42273), all is going really well and there are no warnings but there is one error -

C:\Users\User\Downloads\dsdriv\dsdriv>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\Inf2Cat.exe" /driver:C:\Users\Support\Downloads\dsdriv\dsdriv /os:XP_X64,Server2003_X64,Vista_X64,
7_X64

................................
Signability test failed.

Errors:
22.9.12: INF file (\driver.inf) cannot be copied to %windir%\inf.

Warnings:
None

I've look around Google and I  found results of where people have has similar errors but the solution was not explained, then I tried to use the Chkinf.bat utility that comes with the kit to help me find the error with the INF file but I came across a very strange error that the syntax of the command was incorrect, however I wrote the batch to check the INF file exactly to the [Chkinf Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543462(v=vs.85).aspx) and yet it was still coming up with the syntax error, here is the bat that I compiled to check the driver.inf file -

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Tools\x86\ChkInf\chkinf" "C:\Users\User\Downloads\dsdriv\dsdriv\driver.inf"
```

I also tried -

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Tools\x86\ChkInf\chkinf.bat" "C:\Users\User\Downloads\dsdriv\dsdriv\driver.inf"
```

and -

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Tools\x86\ChkInf\chkinf" C:\Users\User\Downloads\dsdriv\dsdriv\driver.inf /L results.txt /B /LO
```

but no use.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a syntax error - simply an inability to copy the file to %windir%\inf. I also note that the directions say to navigate to the directory containing `chkinf.bat`. Perhaps there's some reason to need to have that directory current. I'd try `pushd thedirectoryinquestion` then `chkinf` and `popd`. Also I'd make sure that `%windir%\inf` is an existing directory and has appropriate permissions. Just a quick couple of suggestions that may help - no guarantees, I've never used `chkinf`.

Answer (score 0):

The ChkInf may not be present in any of the above directories. It is shipped along the WinDDK.

You can find it exactly at

> WinDDK_InstalledPath\Version_of_WinDDK\tools\Chkinf\chkinf.bat

The issue could be due to the [SourceDisksFiles] containing INF copy directives